# Angularjs click clear button inside input but no effect to binded json object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

As title.  I have a page with several inputs with type="text", and set them with clear buttons generated by the js code:

```
function SetClearButtonInTextBox(Callback) {
    if (!window.document.documentMode) {
        $("input").each(function () {
            var im = $(this);
            if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("text-input-wrapper") && !$(this).hasClass("btn")) {
                $(this).wrap("<div class='text-input-wrapper'></div>");
                $(this).after("<button class=\"Covered\" type=\"button\">&times;</button>");
            }
            $(this).closest("div.text-input-wrapper").find("button").mousedown(function () {
                im.val("");
                im.change();
                //return false;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And my inputs like this:

```
<input name="ModelA" ng-model="dl.ModelA" ng-change="ClearText(this,dl.ModelA);" value=""/>
<input name="ModelB" ng-model="dl.ModelB" ng-change="ClearText(this,dl.ModelB);" value=""/>
```

And I made the "ClearText" function as:

```
$scope.ClearText=function(target, ngModelTo){
            if (target.target.value == "") {
                ngModelTo = "";
            }
        }
```

I want when I click the clear button inside input, the binded value and the textbox will also be cleared,  but I found that only my textbox is cleared but the binded value isn't.
Could someone guide me to make it?

Comment: This is really all jquery and DOM manipulation. Angular keeps its own shadow DOM and it's highly discouraged to manipulate it externally - or if so, to use angular's methods. You should ditch jQuery and use the native methods.

Comment: But could I have a way to make it by a function? Because I have many pages with this kind of textbox with this kind of requests,  could I make it by a function that I could apply to many pages?

Comment: Actually, you'd likely make a directive which would contain it's own logic, then use that directive component in place of your inputs. It's a whole rethink - you would not be using a function to scrape over the DOM, you would make a reusable component